# How do i set ip address when using file_get_content() in php?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I am using file_get_content() to open a file from external url. But when i do so, the
url request ip is being set as the server ip instead of the client ip. is there any way to solve  this?

I found this by testing the following code.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"HTTP_CLIENT_IP: $ip" .
            "remote_addr: $ip".
            "server_addr: $ip".
            "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n",
            )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://ifconfig.me/ip', false, $context);
var_dump($file);
```

Output : string(10) "153.92.0.6" (It is my domain ip)
Output i wanted is client ip instead of domain ip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the client IP address in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: I'm actually trying to scrap a website with Simple HTML dom.. The website which I'm scraping contains m3u8 links which is based on tokens generated from the request up address...

Answer (score 1):

> the url request ip is being set as the server ip instead of the client ip.

Well yes. That **is** where the request is coming from.

> is there any way to solve this?

Make the request from the client instead. e.g. with Ajax. Expect the same origin policy to get in the way.

---

If your goal is to get the client's IP address, then `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` already has that and you have no need to go to an external service.

Comment: How to make the request from client? Actually I'm very new to this ... I'm actually trying to scrap a website with Simple HTML dom.. The website which I'm scraping contains m3u8 links which is based on tokens generated from the request up address...